# Is onBindViewHolder being called when in fling scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fling

so my questions are:

- Is onBindViewHolder being called for every item in my recyclerview when in fling scrolling?
- Is it only calling it once the fling is stopping and on the items that are shown on screen? (and the recycled ones as well of course)

Comment: Answers : Yes and No (simple logging could have confirmed this)

Comment: It depends on the situtation. As suggested by @Mark keen , you can use Log to understand the behaviour.